# Can Hadoop mapper produce multiple keys in output?

Tags: hadoop, key, mapper

Can a single Mapper class produce multiple key-value pairs (of same type) in a single run?

We output the key-value pair in the mapper like this:

```
context.write(key, value);
```

Here's a trimmed down (and exemplified) version of the Key:

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;


public class MyKey extends ObjectWritable implements WritableComparable<MyKey> {

    public enum KeyType {
        KeyType1,
        KeyType2
    }

    private KeyType keyTupe;
    private Long field1;
    private Integer field2 = -1;
    private String field3 = "";


    public KeyType getKeyType() {
        return keyTupe;
    }

    public void settKeyType(KeyType keyType) {
        this.keyTupe = keyType;
    }

    public Long getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(Long field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public Integer getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(Integer field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }


    public String getField3() {
        return field3;
    }

    public void setField3(String field3) {
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput datainput) throws IOException {
        keyTupe = KeyType.valueOf(datainput.readUTF());
        field1 = datainput.readLong();
        field2 = datainput.readInt();
        field3 = datainput.readUTF();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput dataoutput) throws IOException {
        dataoutput.writeUTF(keyTupe.toString());
        dataoutput.writeLong(field1);
        dataoutput.writeInt(field2);
        dataoutput.writeUTF(field3);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyKey other) {
        if (getKeyType().compareTo(other.getKeyType()) != 0) {
            return getKeyType().compareTo(other.getKeyType());
        } else if (getField1().compareTo(other.getField1()) != 0) {
            return getField1().compareTo(other.getField1());
        } else if (getField2().compareTo(other.getField2()) != 0) {
            return getField2().compareTo(other.getField2());
        } else if (getField3().compareTo(other.getField3()) != 0) {
            return getField3().compareTo(other.getField3());
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static class MyKeyComparator extends WritableComparator {
        public MyKeyComparator() {
            super(MyKey.class);
        }

        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            return compareBytes(b1, s1, l1, b2, s2, l2);
        }
    }

    static { // register this comparator
        WritableComparator.define(MyKey.class, new MyKeyComparator());
    }
}
```

And this is how we tried to output both keys in the Mapper:

```
MyKey key1 = new MyKey();
key1.settKeyType(KeyType.KeyType1);
key1.setField1(1L);
key1.setField2(23);

MyKey key2 = new MyKey();
key2.settKeyType(KeyType.KeyType2);
key2.setField1(1L);
key2.setField3("abc");

context.write(key1, value1);
context.write(key2, value2);
```

Our job's output format class is: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat

I'm stating this because in other output format classes I've seen the output not appending and just committing in their implementation of write method.

Also, we are using the following classes for Mapper and Context:
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Context

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "type". Are you asking whether you can get the same key associated with several values or same key with same values being generated multiple times?

Comment: I am wanting a single run of the mapper to output two keys each with different value.

Comment: sure this is possible, this is actually the right way of doing things.

Comment: I am doing this but finding problems like the 1st key doesn't seems to be reaching the reducer or not output at all by the mapper. I edited the question to explain better.

Comment: how's the key implementing writablecomparable? please post some code ;D

Comment: Added some code. Hope it helps

Comment: Are you sure that the binary comparator works? And you don't have to extend from objectwritable, you just need to implement writablecomparable.

Comment: Does the key come never up in the reducer?

Comment: Yeah, I only receive key2 in the reducer probably because it's written last.

Comment: And I am extending the key from ObjectWritable.

Comment: you don't need to extend from object writable. It is very strange that the object just vanishes...

Comment: You need to provide equals() and hashCode() methods on your WritableComparable. They aren't part of the interface, but your job will fail without them.

Comment: (I made my explanation into an answer.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Writing to the context multiple times in one map task is perfectly fine.

However, you may have several problems with your key class. Whenever you implement `WritableComparable` for a key, you should also implement `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` methods. These aren't part of the WritableComparable interface, since they are defined in `Object`, but you must provide implementations.

The default partitioner uses the `hashCode()` method to decide which reducer each key/value pair goes to. If you don't provide a sane implementation, you can get strange results.

As a rule of thumb, whenever you implement `hashCode()` or any sort of comparison method, you should provide an `equals(Object)` method as well. You will have to make sure it accepts an `Object` as the parameter, as this is how it is defined in the `Object` class (whose implementation you are probably overriding).